# Google Sheets how can I stitch cells together to form a date?

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a month name in cell A1 like "JUN" how can I use that to create dates?

For instance 6/3/2021

I want to be able to do this A1(JUN)(1st Friday of June),(current year) with the results in another cell.

A1 is dynamic, it can be changed by the user to JUL, AUG, SEP, etc. via a dropdown So you can have...

JUN (1st Friday of June),(current year) -- 6/3/2021

JUL (1st Friday of July),(current year) -- 7/1/2021

AUG (1st Friday of August),(current year) -- 8/6/2021

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula.

```
=DATEVALUE("01-"&A1&YEAR(TODAY())) + (6 - WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("01-"&A1&YEAR(TODAY()))))
```

[image]

Comment: Harun, this formula will work most of the time. However, it will fail if the first day of a month falls on a Saturday (which will back up to the last Friday of the previous month, e.g. JAN of 2022).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that uses a helper function to build a the 1st day of a month using the dropdown values JAN thru DEC

[image]
The formula to make the first day of the month using the dropdown

```
=date(year(today()), match(B59,{"JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP","OCT", "NOV", "DEC"},0),1)
```

The formula to calculate the 1st Friday of that month is:

```
=to_date(index(filter(sequence(days(eomonth(C59,0),C59)+1,1,C59),weekday(sequence(days(eomonth(C59,0),C59)+1,1,C59))=6),1,1))
```

This version does not use a helper function

[image]

The formula is:

```
=to_date(index(filter(sequence(days(eomonth(datevalue("01-"&B64&YEAR(TODAY())),0),datevalue("01-"&B64&YEAR(TODAY())))+1,1,datevalue("01-"&B64&YEAR(TODAY()))),weekday(sequence(days(eomonth(datevalue("01-"&B64&YEAR(TODAY())),0),datevalue("01-"&B64&YEAR(TODAY())))+1,1,datevalue("01-"&B64&YEAR(TODAY()))))=6),1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(A1&"7"),FILTER(SEQUENCE(3650,1,DATEVALUE("1/1/2021")),WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(3650,1,DATEVALUE("1/1/2021")))=6),1,TRUE)`

This will look up the 7th of the month listed in A1 within a list of 10 years' worth of dates `FILTER`ed to only include Fridays. The 7th of the month is used because it is the latest date on which the first Friday can ever fall. And since the `VLOOKUP` uses `TRUE` as the final parameter (possible because the entire list of Friday dates is in perfect sequential order), no matter what day of the week the 7th is, it will also "bump back" and find the closest Friday before it in the `FILTER`ed list.

I should think that a list of dates through 2031 will be far beyond what you'd need (i.e., `3650` days). If you're still using this same sheet in 10 years, you can always just change `2021` to `2031`.